# Take color from other layer with data-override/expression

Tags: qgis, labeling, color

QGIS 3.8, Win. 10. In addition to [a question asked earlier](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/336576/define-color-for-label-buffer-with-data-defined-override-expression), I want to set the color of text-buffers to adapt to the color from another layer in the background. I have a shapeburst-style background (blue) and on top of it the label with buffer. I would like to keep the buffer, but change the color (override) to exactly the same color as the background (which is on another layer): is that possible? Can I create an expression that takes the color dynamically form another layer?

In the screenshot, the label-buffer for name 3a should have a darker blue value on the left and a brighter one on the right.

[image]

I need the buffer to to mask the leader lines that continue below the label. So the buffer does not make sense as it has exactly the same color as the background, but it makes senst to cover the lines.

Comment: The way I understand your question it does not make sense. If the buffer has the same color as the background, then you wouldnt need a buffer at all. Can you please clarify your question?

Comment: I don't think you could get the exact same color as your background is a gradient. But if your goal is just to hide the leaders lines you may ask a question about making leader lines shorter...