# Adding colour range to grid in QGIS

Tags: qgis, vector-grid, color

I am doing some mapping for vegetation monitoring across a site. I have divided the property up into quadrats using the create fishnet grid function at the size I wanted. I have then intersected it with the boundaries of the property, and each quadrat has a number.

For the sake of the mapping I want to give each quadrat a score (0-4) for particular species cover.

How can I get each quadrat to display a different colour depending on the number (0-blue, 1-red etc.)? Below is what I have managed to create with the quadrat numbers on each grid. Would it be easier if I gave each a percentage value? (0=0%, 1=1%-24%, 2=25%-50% etc.).

[image]

Comment: This question answers yours quite good: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/336576/define-color-for-label-buffer-with-data-defined-override-expression